# Django-filters create filter with custom lookup expression

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I'm using django-filters and want to create possibility for users to choose lookup expressions, something like code below, but I don't know how I could provide expression to filter. What I'm trying to get as result is something like Product.objects.filter(description__expression=value). Does anyone knows the way how to do it?

```
class ChooseLookupExprCharFilter(filters.CharFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value, expression='icontains'):
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return qs
        if self.distinct:
            qs = qs.distinct()
        lookup = '%s__%s' % (self.field_name, expression)
        qs = self.get_method(qs)(**{lookup: value})
        return qs

class ProductFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    description = ChooseLookupExprCharFilter(label='description')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'prize')
```

Edit 1:

Actually I found the solution. Code below is exactly what I looked for.

```
    class ProductFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
      description = ChooseLookupExprCharFilter(label='description')

      class Meta:
          model = Product
          fields = {'description': ['istartswith', 'icontains', 'exact']}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you want to apply the lookup on all objects and if you know the lookup field and the expression, you could simply use filter on `filtered_qs = products.objects.filter(lookupfield__contains=expression) ` and `return filtered_qs`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that wasn't exactly what I looked for. Found solution in django-filters documentation :)